# Need to concatenate two audio data

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am new to Python. Here is my problem, I'm getting input via speech recognizer. The user says code like '1234' and again says '3456'. I'm storing each of the audio data in a variable. I need to concatenate these two.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

 text2 = audio

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

text3 = audio
```

I need to concatenate both the data. I have to supply them as the input to a text box.Is there any way to concatenate these data?(text2 and text3) since being an audio. I need it in a variable not as an audio file.

Comment: What are the types you are trying to concatenate (what does `r.listen(source)` return)?

Comment: You just want a variable that stores each of text2 and text3 so they can be passed together, or do you want one continuous audio track saved in one variable?

Comment: @CoffeeBeforeArch r.listen(source) returns type audio.

Comment: @bartcubrich Ya, the data in text2 and the data in text3 have to be merged as one. Let's say, the user says '1234'. It is stored in text2. The user says '2345'. It is stored in text3. I have to concat these two in a single variable. Since it is a audio type i cant do it.

Comment: So the new audio would be '12342345'?

Comment: @Sid are you using the "SpeechRecognition" module? If so, is the data type an instance of "AudioData"? Then do you need something of the type "AudioData" after the concatenation? You are able to get the raw data, or wav formatted data from an "AudioData" instance. These could easily be concatenated.

Comment: @bartcubrich Yep exactly.

Comment: @CoffeeBeforeArch Yep, I'm using speech recognition package. But i need it as a string maybe. I don't want it as a file. Just need it as variable to be passed on as an input to the text box.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in the process is to use a recognizer to turn your `AudioData` instance into a string. You can do this by:

Creating a recognizer using the same module

`r = sr.Recognizer()`

Convert the "AudioData" instance to a string using the recognizer

`some_string1 = r.recognize_sphinx(audio)`

Then just do this for say `some_string2`, and do `some_string1 + some_string2` to concatenate them.

Comment: I tried it, If i say 1234, it is picking it up as some alphabets like 'hhred'. It is not recognizing it properly. But the above method is working  :)

Comment: That probably depends on how good your speech recognition/transcription algorithm is.